# Erlang and method_missing

Tags: erlang, method-missing

I come from a Java and Ruby background and I was wondering if there is any equivalent of "method_missing" in Erlang. I have looked at the documentation and the closest I can see is the use of erl_eval and erl_parse, but I wanted to know if there is any other way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is the 'error_handler' module which is called when you attempt to call an undefined function.

```
process_flag(error_handler, Module).
```

The module needs to export `undefined_function/3` and `undefined_lambda/3`. You can see how this should be implemented in the standard handler module, `error_handler`.

You need to be careful in your own `error_handler` not to break the standard code loading system. Erlang usually tries to load the module from an undefined function error and re-run the function before giving up and signalling an error. You usually want to try the standard error_handler first and fall back to your new behaviour if that fails.

Answer (score 4):

archaelus pointed in a good direction, but if you prefer not to meddle with the `error_handler`, it does support a nice callback routine notifying the module being called that there was an attempt to call an undefined function, which seems quite handy.

https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/kernel/src/error_handler.erl#L139

So if you add this in a module:

```
'$handle_undefined_function'(Func, Args) ->
     io:format("Called undefined function '~p' with args ~p.~n", [Func, Args]).
```

It'll print out a message whenever a call is made to a undefined function in that module.

Comment: Maybe this didn't exist when the question was originally asked, but this is definitely the right answer now. +10 if I could.

Answer (score 3):

If you are into "defensive coding", you can call `Module:module_info(exports)` to see if the function you're about to call is exported or not.

Comment: Useful tip, I tried this and it does provide useful information. Is there any way I can dynamically add a method to this list (to a module I mean) then, as that could be useful

Comment: Check out smerl: http://code.google.com/p/erlyweb/source/browse/trunk/src/smerl/smerl.erl

Answer (score 1):

Erlang has functions not methods and generally trying to call an undefined function is considered to be an error.

The compiler generates an error if you try to call a non-existent function within the same module. Trying to call a function in another module will generate an error at runtime, the `undef` error. How you wish to handle such an error depends on your application.

Comment: So this looks promising. So does this mean that a "function_missing" method could be created for external modules which is invoked at runtime?

Comment: Yes, it could. See @archaelus answer earlier for more details. Be warned though that messing with the error_handler could completely ruin the automatic code loading and really mess up the system if it is not 100% right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a similar pattern on the calling side where a module *may* supply a log level classification function (which *may* return invalid results).  I do it like this:

```
-spec categorize(atom(), integer()) -> log_classification().
categorize(Module, Code) ->
    case catch(Module:ns_log_cat(Code)) of
        info -> info;
        warn -> warn;
        crit -> crit;
        _ -> info % Anything unknown is info (this includes {'EXIT', Reason})
        end.
```

Since there isn't a method (in general, you could certainly create an OO behavior and implement it with messages and then have `method_missing`, the callee doesn't know I attempted anything, so it can't interpret it.

Comment: Is this the same as a default clause in a case statement??

Comment: In this case, I'm matching three known good values and then dealing with any other case (including exceptions and exits) as a default.  I use `_` because I don't care about the results.